# glibc malloc deadlock during string reserve

Tags: c++, gcc, log4cxx

From some time I am trying to catch a problem with my product hanging. This is the call stack I got after coredumping the process with gcore:

```
/lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f36fb339ba6 in _L_lock_12192 () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007f36fb337121 in malloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007f36fbbef0cd in operator new(unsigned long) () from   /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x00007f36fbc4d7e9 in std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x00007f36fbc4e42b in   std::string::_Rep::_M_clone(std::allocator<char> const&, unsigned long) () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x00007f36fbc4e4d4 in std::string::reserve(unsigned long) () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#7  0x00007f36fbc2b3c6 in std::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::overflow(int) () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 
#8  0x00007f36fbc2fb36 in std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::xsputn(char const*, long) () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#9  0x00007f36fbc26885 in std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long) () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#10 0x00007f36fe85c83a in ?? ()
#11 0x00007f36fb2ffdff in vfprintf () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#12 0x000000000055c110 in fgetc@plt ()
#13 0xffffffffffffffa8 in ?? ()
#14 0xffffffffffffffa8 in ?? ()
#15 0x0000000000bc42a0 in ?? ()
#16 0x000000000055b8b0 in setsockopt@plt ()
#17 0x000000000055bf30 in log4cxx::NDC::push ()
```

This is multithreaded code executed after forking a process in log4cxx ndc push seemingly. All the other threads sleep on condition variables and this is the only one deadlocked. What could possibly make malloc deadlock?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't fork processes that use threading.

If one of the other threads has a lock acquired (let's say, the lock in `malloc`) during the fork, *the lock is cloned in locked state*, but the thread that locked it isn't running in the forked process. This means that the lock will never be released.

Comment: The threads start after the forking, so I don't think this is what happened here otherwise this is great idea, so thank you!

Comment: @typical: There could be threads that you didn't create running (i.e. from libraries you've initialized). Set a breakpoint on the `fork` and check.

Comment: @typical: I am sure you believe that, but chances are at least 95% that you are mistaken and this answer is completely correct.

Comment: Thank you all, there are 10 other threads allocating memory after the fork and after this thread being blocked and this is the only one blocked. So I think rather that maybe the log4cxx library could have some problem.